# Orchard CMS Developer's Guide

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.9

I have started looking in Orchard CMS a week ago. When it comes to doing anything on my Orchard website using the Admin dashboard, things look pretty promising. But when it comes to inducing a feature say create a Navigation menu and add a vertical sub menu to it,using the code, I just lose track. I am not able to find any kind of help regarding the technical(code level) features available with Orchard. I have gone through the PluralSight videos as well. But beyond that, nothing.

So, could anyone please provide any links or any samples they might have created so that I get some kind of guidance. 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A full guide to Orchard CMS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206182/a-full-guide-to-orchard-cms)

Comment: @devqon I went through the links provided on the link you have mentioned, but couldn't find anything navigation menus and submenus through code.

Comment: Personally, I used [Orchard CMS: Up and Running by John Zablocki](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920023999.do) as an introduction to the basics. After that I went through the official docs to understand [custom parts](http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Writing-a-content-part/), [placement](http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Understanding-placement-info/) and [data access](http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Understanding-data-access/). After that you'll just want to practice and inspect objects with the debugger.

Comment: @kushagrasharma If all you need right now is to figure something out about navigation, maybe you can ask it as a separate question and explain your specific problem.

Comment: @BauceLawyerson Will go through the book. Thanks.